# 'No Such Property' but Grails sees it and gives a 'Possible solution'?

Tags: grails

I got caught again in some confusing Grails syntax. The error I get is:

> No such property: productDescr for class: grailsTest.ProductType
>   Possible solutions: productDescr

Ironically productDescr suggested by Grails is the property I want to use. Somehow is not found but it knows it should be productDescr.

This is the sample code I'm using...

Model (ProductType.groovy):

```
package grailsTest

class ProductType {

    String productCode
    String productName
    String productDescr

    static constraints = {
        productCode (size: 3..20, unique: true, nullable: false)
        productName (maxSize: 45, blank: false)
        productDescr (maxSize: 500, blank: true)        
    }
}
```

Controller (ProductTypeController.groovy):

```
package grailsTest

class ProductTypeController {
    static scaffold = true

    def showSingleType() {
        def productType = ProductType.findByProductCode("prod1");
        render view: "showSingleType", model: [productType: ProductType]
    }    
}
```

And View (showSingleType.gsp):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Types</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
        Selected product type: ${productType.productDescr }
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I go through the scaffolding first to add my test data (see screen pic).
[image]

Then I change the url to:

```
http://localhost:8080/GrailsTest/productType/showSingleType
```

And the response is this error page:
[image]

Must be some silly setting I missed but I can't see the forest for the trees  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in your model:

```
render view: "showSingleType", model: [productType: ProductType]
```

That should be:

```
render view: "showSingleType", model: [productType: productType]
```

The way that you have it written, the value of the `productType` variable in the model is the `ProductType` class, not the `productType` variable that is initialized in the controller action. Since your GSP is referring to `productType.productDescr` and the value of `productType` there is the `ProductType` class, the system is trying to reference a static property named `productDescr` on the `ProductType` class, and as the error message suggests, that property does not exist.

Comment: That worked. I changed that 'p' in the render command (in the Controller class). Thanks!